# React Native Switch and Toggle API Call

Tags: javascript, react-native, toggleswitch

I am using [React Native Switch][1].

In the **code snippet** below, I am calling two APIs: `apiActive()` and `apiInactive()`.

Based on the `booking_status`, if `booking_status === "0"` it will show `ACTIVE` and if `booking_status === "1"`
it will show `INACTIVE`.

So far, when I press the Switch, it calls the API and `booking_status` changes from `0` to `1` and vice versa. Similarly, Switch's state changes from `false` to `true`.

> However, I am trying to achieve the following objective:
>
> 1. Based on the `booking_status`, I want the Switch to show `true` or `false`. That is, if `booking_status === "0"`, the Switch will stay `false` and if `booking_status === "1"`, the Switch will stay `true` (similar to how `INACTIVE` and `ACTIVE` are displayed).
> 2. Also, when I press the Switch, I want the APIs to be called. For example: if `booking_status === "0"`, after pressing the Switch, it will call `apiActive()` and at the same time the Switch state will change to `true` and text will change from `INACTIVE` to `ACTIVE` and vice versa.

**Code Snippet:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Picker,
    ActivityIndicator,
} from 'react-native';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import Constants from '../../constants/Constants';
    import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
    
    class Datelist extends Component {
    
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                switchValue: false,
            }
        }

        apiActive() {
            //api call active
        }
    
        apiInactive() {
            //api call inactive
        }

        toggleSwitchStatus = (value) => {
            {
                this.props.booking_status === "0" ?
                    this.apiActive() :
                    this.apiInactive();
            }
    
            this.setState({ switchValue: value })
            console.log('Status: ', value);
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <ScrollView>
                    <View style={styles.mf_container}>
                        <TouchableOpacity>
                            <Text style={styles.textStartDate}>{this.props.date_start} status: {this.props.booking_status}</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
    
                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity
                                style={styles.center}
                            >
                                {
                                    <Text style={styles.inactive}>
                                        {
                                            this.props.booking_status === "0" ?
                                                <Text style={{ color: 'red', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>INACTIVE</Text> :
                                                <Text style={{ color: 'green', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>ACTIVE</Text>
                                        }
                                    </Text>
                                }
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            {
                                <Switch
                                    style={styles.center}
                                    onValueChange={this.toggleSwitchStatus}
                                    value={this.state.switchValue}
                                />
                            }
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>
            );
        }
    }
    
    export default withNavigation(Datelist);
```

*I have been trying to solve this for the last couple of hours but it's really annoying at this point. If the API code is required I would gladly add it.*
[1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/switch